# Why my listview only detects the first checkbox?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

i got a problem with my listview. basically consists of a list generated from a search in database, but when loading the list, only detects the first checkbox as checked or unchecked,  ignoring the rest.

the code is this:

```
public void AnyadirProdLista() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ListView lista = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListaProds);
    CheckBox check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkLista);
    int contador = lista.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++){
        if (check.isChecked()){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "a" + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

when i do this and click the button that activate this method, only if the first check box of the list ( the 0 position item in the list ) makes work the toast and do it all the loop, but the other checkbox do nothing.

I do focusable false the checkbox in the view, and don't know nothing more to do, if someone can help me i will be very thankful.

Comment: Is this java? If so, you should add a java tag.

Comment: No, is android, sorry i forgot the tag, ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CheckBox check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkLista);
```

you get one check box and you only check the one you got above

```
if (check.isChecked()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "a" + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

while you iterate throw your list you should overwrite "check" with an other checkbox

Comment: then i should "create" a check for everyone element on my list?

Comment: does every element in the list has it's own "checkbox" ? or does they all "share" one checkbox eg. checkbox == true => output all elements ?

Comment: No, they don't share checkbox, all element got his own checkbox, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Yes, then this is (could be) the problem. You have to query the checkbox for **every** list element. I'm not that familiar with andorid to get you code for that, sorry.